# Changing innerHTML of div clears the whole content

Tags: javascript, dom

*Aka: why are `<div></div>` and `<div />` not equivalent to each other?*

Consider the following HTML + js:

```js
setTimeout(function() { 
    document.getElementById("message2").innerHTML = "blah";
}, 1000);
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="message2" />
        <div id="message1" >Hello</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, when executing the snippet, first "Hello" is shown, and briefly afterwards, "Hello" disappears (*) and "blah" is shown. (I.e. the `innerHTML` of `message2` was changed, and, as a side-effect, `message1` disappeared.)

(*) I checked this on two different browsers (Linux/FF and Mac/Safari), so I'm quite confident this is not a browser-specific issue.

If, on the other hand, `message2` is expanded to opening/closing tags, then changing its `innerHTML` won't affect `message1`:

```js
setTimeout(function() { 
  document.getElementById("message2").innerHTML = "blah";
}, 1000);
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="message2" ></div>  <!-- notice that it was expanded -->
        <div id="message1" >Hello</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Questions:**

- Why does the other div disappear in the first case?
- Why do the "compact" and the "expanded" form have different effects? (I thought they were fully equivalent.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This div `<div id="message2" />`  is not closed as you think it is. Here is a list of [HTML's self closing tags](http://xahlee.info/js/html5_non-closing_tag.html). Note that div is not one of them.

See this:

```js
setTimeout(function() { 
  document.getElementById("message2").innerHTML = "blah";
}, 1000);
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
        <div id="message2" >
  <div id="message1" >Hello</div>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

So in your second snippet you just change innerHTML of the first div, while second just sits there.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I'm one step nearer. I understand *what* is happening, but not *why*. (Why is the div tag not closed as I think it is?)

Comment: Here is a list of HTML's self closing tags - http://xahlee.info/js/html5_non-closing_tag.html . Note that `div` is not one of them

Comment: "Note that div is not one of them" -- oh, I see, I did not know this. (I thought **all** tags were self-closing :) ) Please consider adding this info to the answer, as it it quite important IMHO.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly the following is going on: in `message2`-div the closing slash is ignored, so it becomes an unclosed div. And the browser then implicitly adds the closing tag at the end of the body-part.

Comment: Yes, I think that happens - browser adds closing div. In either way, your second div becomes innerHTML of the first div